# Why <big> is not in HTML 5 Tag list while <small> is?

Tags: css, xhtml, web-standards, semantic-markup, html

Shouldn't both be removed? Or does it mean we should use `<small>`? Why is `<big>` removed but `<small>` is not? What is the problem with `<big>` which does not apply to `<small>`?

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_reference.asp

Comment: HTML 5 reminds me of the phrase "A camel is a horse designed by a committee."

Comment: A camel may not be as quick but it survives harsh desert environments a lot better than a horse.

Comment: I just had the same thought. I wonder if we can still use `<big>` just like we can use the `<b>` tag to sneak things into the page. I guess I'll have to test what "obsolete" really means.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/big

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Remember, the tags are meant to be semantic, not presentational. There is such a thing in English as "fine print". This is what the small tag represents. There is no analogous concept of "big print" except for a header, which is already covered by seven other tags.

Comment: +1. Excellent point about semantics and clearly the best answer so far.

Comment: but with css we can convert any tag to small size.

Comment: @JitendraVyas There is a lot of overlap between HTML and CSS, *visually*.  HTML has semantic meaning, however, while CSS does not.

Comment: HTML isn't semantic in the sense that, say, schema.org vocabularies are semantic, ie it doesn't say "this text is a link to a comment on this article" or "this text is the name of the author".  But it is semantic in the sense that it's a common starting point where even without looking at the styling, all user agents can agree that "this text is probably intended to be smaller/quieter than other text".  And as Chuck rightly points out, there are already other great tags for expressing that text should be bigger/louder already.

Comment: @JitendraVyas Think in terms of accessibility.

Comment: The seven other tags don't suffice to express what <big> expressed.  In particular, if I'm in the middle of a <h1> and I want to go bigger / louder / "more headerly" for a bit, I'm out of luck.

Comment: @DonHatch: It seems to me that you have `<em>`, `<strong>` and `<b>` if you want to go semantically bigger or louder, and CSS if you want a specific presentational effect.

Comment: HTML stands for Hypertext Markup language. Given that "Hypertext" and "Markup" both literally mean "big text", the big tag should definitely be there. There is no good justification for removing it.  Big (along with Center) should definitely be brought back.  Header tags are for headers.  Text need not be a header to be big - there is no imperative correlation.

Comment: @BlueWater One could argue that big text is automatically interpreted by the reader as a header, because that is what headers always look like. There is no equivalent for small text.

Comment: A header is a header.  Big text is just that; big text.  it doesn't have to be anything else.  Sometimes a cigar is just a cigar.

Answer (score 10):

`<small>` is used more frequently, for footnotes and such...with `<h1>`, `<h2>` and `<h3>` there just wasn't a use for `<big>`, hence why it's removed.

Comment: "<small> is used more frequently, for footnotes and such...with <h1>, <h2> and <h3>" could you give more details on this?

Comment: This doesn't quite cut it. Tags such as `<center>` or `<font>` used to be (and from what I can tell, *still* are) much more popular than `<small>`. Yet, they have been declared as deprecated.

Comment: @Jitendra - Just think about daily web design, I've never needed a header when h1, h2 and h3 wouldn't do the job...but there isn't a great equivalent for the small end of things like footnotes, this is where some developers use `<small>`, I prefer a `<span>` or a `<p>`, but a lot of developers use `<small>` meaning removing it would have much more of an impact than removing `<big>`.  Also keep in mind that although they're not "in the spec" browsers will probably still support both for some time.

Comment: @RegDwight - I agree they should **all** be removed, don't get me wrong.  I'm just illustrating why it wasn't, not that I agree with it.  From the docs: "The small element now represents small print (for side comments and legal print)." http://dev.w3.org/html5/html4-differences/

Comment: that quote from the docs actually supports the very point I'm trying to make. The `<small>` tag is kept because it has a semantic value (side comments and legal print), *not* because it is popular (which, again, it even isn't when compared to some of the other tags that have been dropped). Popularity has nothing to do with this.

Comment: `<center>` was a bad idea to begin with - it's a block-level element but its purpose is to dictate something stylistic.  Even without CSS it should not have been an element, so removing it was removing a poor design decision.  `<font>` made a bit more sense before CSS was created, it's just that CSS made it obsolete, and that's why it was removed.  `<small>` could have faced the same fate except that people agree that `<small>` can convey a meaning that goes beyond mere styling.  But yeah, elements are not removed from the spec based on their *popularity*.

Comment: An example of when I use `<small>`: To enclose the text "*All fields are required*" in forms. Is that presentational? Maybe. Is that semantic? Maybe as well. Certainly something discretional but the type of content I'm dealing with merits the use of `<small>` to me.

Comment: Who are you to say there wasn't a use for Big?  Everyone who was using it had a use for it.

Comment: @thomasrutter the center tag was a great idea, and people are still using it, including myself, esp since everything mobile is centered.  Trying to center a page using CSS is often a giant disaster, and unnecessarily so.  If it ain't broke, don't fix it.  Development time should not consist of having to figure out how a language works simply because the language is cumbersome or idiosyncratic.  Algorithms are difficult enough as it is.  All of HTML and CSS are both stylistic.  The data is in the database.  What are these post-modern professors teaching these days?

Answer (score 6):

The same logic that applies to small (as "fine print") is also just as true for big (as "warning"). Public postings, mostly, but also manuals or even contracts often have things written in bigger fonts that signify [so... semantics!] a warning.

It's not the same as emphasis, which has a meaning in context, but rather "whatever you skip in this text, this part you should read because it's not the usual blah blah but something with immediate and important consequences"

That's why I think big and small should both be out or both in.

Comment: +1.  The folks who decide what's in and what's out often get tunnel vision.  For example, right this moment I'm being warned "Comments cannot contain that content. Don't comment on your upvote. Please write constructive, detailed commentary focused on the contents of the post. See The Comment Privilege".

Comment: On the one hand, I agree with this answer. We need both <big> and <small>! On the other hand, isn't it just that we remember <big> and that's the reason we want to keep it? What about other "complementary" pairs? <strong> would need a complement such as <weak> (with a lighter font weight). But we never had that, so we don't miss it. Similarly, we have <th> elements for table headers, but no <tf> elements. Etc.

Answer (score 3):

Some purely presentational tags managed to slip through into the spec before but the 2 standards bodies have finally reached a concesus to remove all purely presentational tags in favour of using CSS. If something has no semantic value and is purely for visual apearance - it does NOT belong in the markup - it belongs in a stylesheet.

Comment: While I'm sure there's truth in this answer, it doesn't seem to actually address the question.